# Ipad Safari Meteor apps crashes (iPhone does not)

Tags: javascript, ios, mongodb, ipad, meteor

I have a problem on my Meteor app. On every device, it's working well and fast.

When I go to iPad (with the simulator or a real device), it's keeping crashing telling me at the end:
A problem repeatedly occurred on "url"

This happens when trying to load a collection. This collection has 36 documents, which are 120kb each approximately. If I don't load this collection, the problem doesn't happen. 67KB per document (more or less) are really loaded since a part is stripped out when publishing.

If I remove 5 documents in the collection, the problem doesn't happen anymore too.

I got a report with the simulator saying (I put only the relevant lines):

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000bbadbeef
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0xbbadbeef:
    WebKit Malloc          00000000b0800000-00000000bb800000 [176.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> 
    Stack Guard            00000000bbf09000-00000000bf709000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 201.3 - Device: iPad 2 - Runtime: iOS 9.2 (13C75) - DeviceType: iPad 2

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04cab966 bmalloc::VMHeap::grow() + 150
1   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04caa8b9 bmalloc::Heap::allocateLarge(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 153
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04ca7ba6 bmalloc::Allocator::allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long) + 838
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04c7cc63 WTF::fastAlignedMalloc(unsigned long, unsigned long) + 51
4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0477eb5b JSC::CopiedSpace::tryAllocateOversize(unsigned long, void**) + 43
5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0477eda5 JSC::CopiedSpace::tryReallocateOversize(void**, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 53
6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0477ece4 JSC::CopiedSpace::tryReallocate(void**, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 132
7   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04a51894 JSC::JSObject::ensureLengthSlow(JSC::VM&, unsigned int) + 228
8   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04a541fc void JSC::JSObject::putByIndexBeyondVectorLengthWithoutAttributes<(unsigned char)8>(JSC::ExecState*, unsigned int, JSC::JSValue) + 796
9   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04a50d04 JSC::JSObject::putDirectIndexBeyondVectorLength(JSC::ExecState*, unsigned int, JSC::JSValue, unsigned int, JSC::PutDirectIndexMode) + 1012
10  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04ad4dd6 JSC::LiteralParser<unsigned short>::parse(JSC::ParserState) + 4294
11  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04a5cf2b JSC::JSONProtoFuncParse(JSC::ExecState*) + 923
12  ???                             0x8980555d 0 + 2306889053
13  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04aee8e7 llint_entry + 17129
14  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04aee8e7 llint_entry + 17129
15  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04aee8e7 llint_entry + 17129
16  ???                             0x898e6ed1 0 + 2307813073
17  ???                             0x89820479 0 + 2306999417
18  ???                             0x89805717 0 + 2306889495
19  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04aeea8c llint_entry + 17550
20  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04aee8e7 llint_entry + 17129
21  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04aee8e7 llint_entry + 17129
22  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04aee8e7 llint_entry + 17129
23  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04aea477 vmEntryToJavaScript + 253
24  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x049b17dc JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 172
25  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04996ca9 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 425
26  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x04739fa1 JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 97
27  com.apple.WebCore               0x0579d4df WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 911
28  com.apple.WebCore               0x053d8cee WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>&) + 814
29  com.apple.WebCore               0x053d88fc WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*) + 268
30  com.apple.WebCore               0x053d87dc WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 92
31  com.apple.WebCore               0x05fcc923 WebCore::WebSocket::didReceiveMessage(WTF::String const&) + 115
32  com.apple.WebCore               0x05fcca3b non-virtual thunk to WebCore::WebSocket::didReceiveMessage(WTF::String const&) + 27
33  com.apple.WebCore               0x05fd1674 WebCore::WebSocketChannel::processFrame() + 5188
34  com.apple.WebCore               0x05fcf95e WebCore::WebSocketChannel::processBuffer() + 94
35  com.apple.WebCore               0x05fcf8d6 WebCore::WebSocketChannel::didReceiveSocketStreamData(WebCore::SocketStreamHandle*, char const*, int) + 374
36  com.apple.WebCore               0x05d93087 WebCore::SocketStreamHandle::readStreamCallback(unsigned long) + 407
37  com.apple.WebCore               0x05d91f8e WebCore::SocketStreamHandle::readStreamCallback(__CFReadStream*, unsigned long, void*) + 30
38  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00d16bbd _signalEventSync + 189
39  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00d4ea7f _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 463
40  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00cd46ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
41  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00cca328 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 424
42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00cc97a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00cc90e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
44  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00cc8efb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
45  com.apple.Foundation            0x001c17c2 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
46  com.apple.Foundation            0x00267cbf -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 82
47  libxpc.dylib                    0x0252b1b3 _xpc_objc_main + 486
48  libxpc.dylib                    0x0252df12 xpc_main + 215
49  com.apple.WebKit.WebContent     0x000f96b3 0xf8000 + 5811
50  libdyld.dylib                   0x02263a21 start + 1
```

It seems to be a memory issue but since I'm only subscribing to a collection, I've difficulties seeing how I can address this issue.

---

EDIT:

Reproducing the issue is pretty simple actually.

It only needs to create such a database with dummy data inside (about same size).

Generate a test app (I did it with iron cli), create the collection, add a publish in server, subscribe in client side (in the controller), get the home page through the iOS simulator with iPad2, it fails (just tested myself). Even, if the app is totally empty...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information about the exception itself. Could you also try and come up with the code necessary to generate such an exception? That way someone could copy it into their own projects and debug the issue. You also seem to be having a `badbeef` issue, check for a rotten meat smell =p

Comment: So I tried, created a new app, just subscribing to the collection makes the browser crashes...